# Python add 1d array to 2d array by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1d array and 2d array

```
a = [4,7,10]
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a.shape = (2,)
b.shape = (3,3)
```

I want:

```
c = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10]]
c.shape = (3,4)
```

I tried `np.vstack`, `np.concenrate` but all failed

Comment: What error did you get?  Try to learn from the error messages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack([b,a])
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try somethings and fail, you should show the work and error.  You might learn something in the process.

```
In [19]: a = np.array([4,7,10])
    ...: b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
In [20]: np.vstack((a,b))
Out[20]: 
array([[ 4,  7, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

`vstack` works, but adds the **V**ertically, as the name implies.

To join them horizontally we need to specify axis 1:

```
In [28]: np.concatenate((b,a), axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-28-52d167b3d573>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate((b,a), axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

`vstack` joins them vertically (axis 0), and adjusts dimensions as needed.

But it's easy to add a dimension to `a`.  `reshape` can do it, also:

```
In [29]: a[:,None].shape
Out[29]: (3, 1)

In [30]: np.concatenate((b,a[:,None]), axis=1)
Out[30]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

If you look at the code for `column_stack` as suggested in the other answer, you'll see that it does this - adds dimensions as needed.

The core join function is `concatenate`.  Learn to adjust dimensions, and you can doing all kinds of joins without remembering all the different names.